# Hot glue in circuit

Tags: glue

I have found some cheap hot glue sticks on eBay but i am not sure if this will work for me. I want to make my circuit stable and stick it into a piece of plastic.

I have found [these](http://www.ebay.com/itm/18x-Hot-Melt-Glue-Stick-7mm-x-9-5cm-for-Craft-Electric-Tool-Heating-Glue-Gun-/321704127702?) sticks that are pretty cheap and 7mm is ideal for me. DO they have any risk of getting the circuit to sort or any other danger?

Comment: Unlikely it will short anything. The only thing you should worry of, is how well it will stick to your materials.

Comment: EE.SE is not a volunteer support desk for that eBya seller.  Ask him.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://i61.tinypic.com/20t2fl4.png

This is the response from the e-bay seller on your question.

You might want to ask him directly for more questions on hot glue.

(Ignore the Dutch parts)